# Проблема в запуске с opencv на С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

При запуске проекта вылазит ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом данный файл указан [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .dll надо положить рядом с .exe.

Comment: Это помогло спасибо! Но я не понимаю почему этот файл находиться там где он ек должен быть?

Comment: Потому что винда, в отличие от линукса, ищет динамические библиотеки рядом с экзешником и в PATH, а не там где они были при линковке.

Comment: Ну и MSVC не умеет линковаться напрямую с .dll, поэтому "где он был при линковке" теряет смысл...